# Deployment error - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I am working on a symfony application and have recently tried to deploy my work to the server due to having a working login, registration etc.

All is working well locally! note though i am using the RDS database on my localhost. i am not using a dev database.

Originally it was complaining about my PHP version on the server so i updated it to 5.6 and redepolyed, and now i'm getting the following in my logs!

```
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache


[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


[RuntimeException]                                                             
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:      

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused    


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    


  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    

.                                                                              


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
(Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2016-01-12T16:22:49.583Z] ERROR [2219]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
```

Any more info need just ask an ill update! any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This mean that doctrine can't establish connection to your database.

When you are deploying a symfony app composer look for `parameters.yml.dist` and copy all those parameters in the file `parameters.yml` which will be used to configure symfony and any other bundle.

You need to set in the `parameters.yml.dist` the correct info of your database (host address, username, password, database name)

Comment: Its not my parameters file sadly, was what i first checked!

Comment: is your database up and running ? is it listening on the correct port ? can you check the connection in console with the same username?

Comment: Yes! i can still persist data to it using doctrine.. :/

Comment: you can persist data in deployment environment or in your local

Comment: In the local of course, my deployment environment is the issue :/

Comment: Are you sure that the parameters.yml.dist is well configured

Answer (score 1):

The connection is refused so it is time for a systematic debug process:

1. Identify the host, user, and password being used to connect. These will be in wherever Symfony stores such things.
2. If those details are present and look correct then use them to log into your database directly (via the command line) to verify that they actually are correct.
3. Check the hostname actually resolves to where the database is hosted. For example, if the database is on the same machine as PHP and the hostname used is `db-production` then check on your Operating System's hosts file for this entry and make sure it resolves to `127.0.0.1`. Typically I would expect the host is set to `localhost`, in which case you can still check the hosts file, but it will probably be in there.
4. Once you have established that the host, user, and password are correct the only thing left is Symfony not behaving as expected. In which case I am all out of ideas.

Comment: This was my first intialal thought, symfony stores the connection details in a parameters.yml file and my connection details are correct, I appreciate you help though

Comment: @Calvin - and everything working but only symfony can't connect to db? You database ban symfony applications? Check one more time, I'll not surpise if you try use dev environment and you have database setup in config_dev.